# Where to store web authentication session in PySide?

Tags: python, django, pyside

I'm building a little application in Python. I use PySide for the GUI and Django to read data from my web application.

Everything works well, but I have a login access, like dropbox application.

I want to store this informations on the current machine (like a session, I don't want to login every time I open the application).

Now my question is, what is the safest way to do this? Environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you have an API that you're exposing in your app to the outer world (even your own desktop/mobile app), you'll design this API to be stateless, as part of the [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Stateless) architecture. So your app should always include an HTTP header or any other method of carrying an authentication token that will let your API identify the user.

You only log in once, and when the log-in procedure is successful you should get an authentication token from your API, and then you will store this token somewhere safe.

You can also look into implementing [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) for the authentication.

Comment: Thanks for this ! I was a bit lost :')